# Quick Fix of Texlipse spell checker is not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, latex

Problem:
    The mis-spelt word are highlighted by the editor. However, when I try to correct the mis-spelt word using Quick-fix, the pop-up window is black

Installation:
    Eclipse SDK 4.2.2 with Texlipse Plugin

Comment: Solved!! ---I realized that there are two spell-checkers. One belongs to the eclipse and the other one belongs to texlipse. The two spell-checkers conflicts a bit. #######

First I tell the spell checker of eclipse to ignore all .tex files (by adding .tex to the excluded file types):
    preferences -> spelling -> excluded file types: ... + .tex
#####
Then I enable the spell checker of texlipse:
    preferences -> texlipse -> spell checker -> use build-in spell checker  ####

Then I restarted eclipse and everything seems fine.

Comment: Please resolve your question if you have solved it.

Answer (score 3):

I realized that there are two spell-checkers. One belongs to the eclipse and the other one belongs to texlipse. The two spell-checkers conflicts a bit.

First I tell the spell checker of eclipse to ignore all .tex files (by adding .tex to the excluded file types):
    preferences -> spelling -> excluded file types: ... + .tex

Then I enable the spell checker of texlipse:
    preferences -> texlipse -> spell checker -> use build-in spell checker

Then I restarted eclipse and everything seems fine.